# .NetCore приложение работающее в диапазоне версий дотнет

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

Я делаю десктопное приложение Windows Forms которое юзеры должны ставить себе на рабочие машины. В качестве целевого фреймворка указал net.core 3.1. Сетап для приложения создается с помощью Advanced Installer, и там я в требованиях к софту указываю тот самый фреймворк.

Столкнулся с проблемой: инсталятор просто говорит что дотнета нет и надо поставить. Причем это в случае если его нет вообще. А вот если есть другая версия то ему норм. Юзеры идут на Майкрософт, качают последнюю версию (сейчас это шестая), а приложение под ней не работает так как хочет именно 3.1. Система показывает меседж бокс, но тут уже есть кнопочка для скачивания нужной версии. Это все сбивает с толку пользователей, а так как они за это еще и платят то возникает некоторое недовольство.

Надо как-нибудь сделать процесс понятнее и проще. Как варианты решения я вижу:

*Научить Advanced Installer проверять наличие конкретно версии 3.1, показывать ссылку на скачивание нужной версии*

или

*Сбилдать приложение так чтоб оно работало на любой версии кора от 3.1 и выше*

Я буду очень благодарен за советы по обеим пунктам!

Comment: Так 3.1 до сих пор поддерживается, с чего вы взяли, что после установки .net 6 ничего не будет работать?

Comment: Не совсем так. Оно не работает если установлен ТОЛЬКО net6. Проверил на виртуалке.

Comment: self-contained сборку не рассматриваете совсем? Да приложение "потяжелеет", но все необходимое будет на борту и пользователям ничего дополнительно качать и устанавливать не потребуется.

Comment: Да, в итоге сделали self-contained. Потяжелело конечно. Но бизнес просил скорейшего результата.